# test cases permutation in test suite - how to avoid repetitive codes for same steps

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to permutate test cases with different values in cypress in a quicker way instead of keeping copy-paste the same line of code over and over?

```
the example below, how to avoid repeating the "long steps of click abcd" at every test case?
Test Suite to select items.
Test Case 1: long steps of click abcd, select 1a,2a
Test Case 2: long steps of click abcd, select 1a,2b
Test Case 3: long steps of click abcd, select 1b,2a
Test Case 4: long steps of click abcd, select 1b,2b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try abstracting the long step to a function

```js
const doLongSteps = (p1, p2) => {
  // long steps of click abcd
}

it(..., () => {
  doLongSteps(1a,2a)
  expect(...
})

it(..., () => {
  doLongSteps(1a,2b)
  expect(...
})
```

or a data-driven approach

```js
const data = [[1a,2a], [1a,2b], [1b,2a], [1b,2b]]

data.forEach(params => {

  it(`tests params ${params}`, () => {
    const [p1, p2] = params   // destructure individual params
    // long steps of click abcd
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cypress custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Syntax) for this:

Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write all your repetitive steps and pass the different parameters as per your use case. Below is the example of Clicking link containing text:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('clickLink', (label) => {
  cy.get('a').contains(label).click()
})
```

In your test-

```js
cy.clickLink('Login')
cy.clickLink('Logout')
```

With the same custom command, we can click the 'Login' and 'Logout' buttons, just by changing the 'label' value with parameters.